# Paypal shipping options

Tags: django, paypal, payment, django-paypal

I'm using `github.com/dcramer/django-paypal.git`, what I sell are features for my webpage, so I don't need shipping info.

As some customers have told me that, they don't want to give their address, I want to accept payments without shipping information.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to hide that field in your site, and always send a specific address as the shipping address. Unless PayPal thinks its some kind of fraud it should work.

If the only thing you are going is creating a PP button, You have no control over what information PayPal asks for. ( As the button redirects them to PayPal's Site.) I am not sure if subscription Buttons work for you, but they may not ask for a shipping address.

Finally, your end Users can just enter some fake address, either to you or two PayPal. If your not actually gonna ship anything it doesn't matter.

**EDIT**: Did a bit more looking and found this. It is [PayPal Documentation on Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/). maybe useing BUTTONSUBTYPE

```
(Optional) The use of button you want to create. It is one of the following values:
PRODUCTS - button is used to purchase products; default for Buy Now and Add to Cart buttons
SERVICES - button is used to purchase services
```

**EDIT2**: Also see [this](https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_std-variable-ref-buy-now.html#HTMLVariablesforPrepopulatingPayPalPaymentPages). Look for `no_shipping` in **Payment Pages** section.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that the fake address will work, but, as it redirects me to the paypal site, and I can control some things as the amount, return url and thigs like that, you sure there's no way to make it not necessary to ask for address?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the subscription. Those are likely to be a virtual product so it may not ask for a shipping address.